# И (Но) (,) зажегши свечу, не ставят ее под сосудом, но на подсвечнике. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Согласно правилу, *деепричастный оборот, стоящий после союза сочинительного или подчинительного либо союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (такой оборот можно «оторвать» от союза и переставить в другое место предложения):*
**Но, рассмотрев всесторонне своё положение в роли мужа Вареньки, он засмеялся?** (М. Т.); **И, подойдя ко мне, сказал…**

- Но в данном предложении оборот "зажегши свечу" нельзя переставить в другое место...
  Получается, запятая не нужна?
- И (Но) в вопросе — варианты союзов.

Comment: @Aer Я поменяла метку "синтакис" на "синтаксис". Надо бы из списка меток удалить ошибочную ("синтакис"), чтоб никого не смущала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст **евангельский**, поэтому имеет определенные особенности.

Кажется, одно из толкований его такое: "Когда человек получает от Бога озарение, просвещение его разума, он не прячется, а старается поведать всему миру то, что получил от Бога даром!"

1) **Второй союз НО заменяет современный союз А**, это не редактируется.

2) **Запятая перед оборотом в приведенных текстах ставится или не ставится**: кто-то формально применяет правило, кто-то ориентируется на невозможность перестановки оборота (тогда союз относится к обороту). У классиков точного ответа нет, мне ситуация кажется вариативной (можно брать любой вариант и объяснить его).

3) **Первый союз НО сомнителен**, в текстах практически везде стоит союз И.

Вообще говоря, присоединительный союз И реже обособляется, чем НО (в различных конструкциях).

Примеры:

**И зажегши свечу**, не ставят её под сосудом, но на подсвечнике, и светит всем в доме. [Александр Алексеев. Правдивые евангелисты // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]

**И, зажегши свечу,** не ставят ее под сосудом, но на подсвечнике, и светит всем в доме. [Виктор Бондарев. Над пропастью во лжи (2003) // «Независимая газета», 2003.03.31]

**И, зажегши свечу,** не ставят ее под сосудом, но на подсвечнике, и светит всем в доме. [Евангелие от Матфея: синодальный перевод (1816-1862)]

Никто, **зажегши свечу**, не покрывает ее сосудом, или не ставит под кровать, а ставит на подсвечник, чтобы входящие видели свет. [Евангелие от Луки: синодальный перевод (1816-1862)]

Несколько лет провел преподобный Стефан в трудах и молитве, которым не суждено было остаться в тайне, ибо никто **зажегши свечу**, не ставит ее в сокровенном месте… но на подсвечнике, чтобы входящие видели свет (Лк. [Обитель преподобного Стефана (2004) // «Журнал Московской патриархии», 2004.08.30]

Answer (score 0):

Два *но* в одном предложении - перебор.

Оба союза (*но* и *и*) кажутся притянутыми за уши. Их роль непонятна. Нужен контекст.

*Не ставят, но на подсвечнике* - неверное согласование. Корректно: ставят не туда, а (но) сюда.